# I need run springboot in netbeans

Tags: spring-boot, netbeans

Spring boot in Netbeans

Hi, I'm trying to make a web app, for this I need to open Spring boot in Netbeans, but when I try to execute a new project, I get the following message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJllN.png)

Scanning for projects...

-----------------------< com.ejemplo:SpringBoot >----------------------- Building SpringBoot 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
--- exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (default-cli) @ SpringBoot --- Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal Application.java Command execution failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404) at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166) at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:1000) at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:947) at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:471) at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498) at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:53) at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:152) at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:76)
BUILD FAILURE
Total time: 1.484 s Finished at: 2023-05-03T23:30:02-03:00

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (default-cli) on project SpringBoot: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

I try to find an answerd

Apache NetBeans IDE 17

C:\Users\USUARIO>java -version
java version "1.8.0_361"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_361-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.361-b09, mixed mode)

[Spring Initializr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSBwt.png)

[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1JYL.png)

(I delete the ? after <)

<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.6
 

com.ejemplo
SpringBoot
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
SpringBoot
Mi primer proyecto con Spring Boot

<java.version>17</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: The fully qualified name of your `Application` class is `com.ejemplo.SpringBoot.Application`. If you do not reference this in your POM, then in NetBeans, go to File > Project Properties > Run - and look in the "Main Class" field. It needs to refer to the full name of the class containing your `main` method. So I assume that is `com.ejemplo.SpringBoot.Application`. You cannot just use `Application` there. **Separate note**: Java 8 is old. You should upgrade to a more modern version of Java.

Comment: Please do not show code using screenshots - in your case, the screenshots are difficult to read (for me, anyway). Please take a look at why you should not upload [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) when asking a question.

Comment: NetBeans 17 does not support Java 8: [The Apache **NetBeans 17 binary releases require JDK 11+**, and officially support running on JDK 11, 17 and 19.](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb17/). Upgrade your JDK to a version supported by NetBeans 17, and update your question if you still have problems.

Comment: @skomisa yes! thanks
Was that
so I updated jdk and that's it

Comment: @Manuco That's good. Please post an answer to your own question, explaining the resolution for your problem. Having answered questions is much more useful to the SO community than having resolution posted in the comments.